# How to round to 2 decimal places in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

In cell B2 I have variable with the value 297.123 before doing calculations In VBA I would like to round this to 297.12. See the code below as to what I have tried. Both have evaluated fuel to 297. What am I doing wrong?

```
Dim fuel As Integer
Dim linecount As Long

linecount2 = 2

fuel = Format(ws.Cells(linecount2, 2), "0.00")
fuel = Round(ws.Cells(linecount2, 2), 2)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change `Dim fuel As Long` -> `Dim fuel As Double`

And both of your formula will work.

```
Dim fuel As Double
Dim linecount2 As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")


linecount2 = 2

fuel = Format(ws.Cells(linecount2, 2), "0.00")
fuel = Round(ws.Cells(linecount2, 2), 2)
fuel = WorksheetFunction.Round(ws.Cells(linecount2, 2), 2) '@suggested by T.M.


MsgBox "try"

End Sub
```

- `Dim Long` is for Integers (whole numbers)
- `Dim Double` is for numbers with decimal points (can store more decimal
  points, up to 15 digits)
- `Dim Single` is for numbers with decimal points (store less decimal
  points, up to 7 digits)

Comment: Thank you!! Take care :)

Comment: Using `Round` only you are executing *Banker's rounding* with possibly unwanted results: it is a standard form of rounding used in financial and statistical operations in order to minimize significant rounding errors over multiple rounding operations by consistently rounding midpoint values in a single direction. 
In order to avoid so called **banker's rounding** (= midpoint value 5 always rounds to the nearest even number ) you can/should use 
**`WorkSheetFunction.Round`** instead.

Comment: Thank you, I have added that :)

Comment: @Anthony  have in mind that Integer takes values from -32,768 to 32,767.If in any case you must handle number outside those intervals you may use Long (-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. )